# Why was my question closed as not constructive? 

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49743/why-did-the-developers-choose-koreans

I asked *Why did they?* and got a very exacting answer... and THEN it was closed.

Please explain this to me.

I fail to see how it violates any of the not constructive guidelines in the FAQ.

Comment: In the more general case, how do you prove there *isn't* an exacting answer and thus we must proceed to a closure?

Comment: The only reason it was closed after it got an exacting answer... is because it was answered before a moderator could get to it to close it in the first place. I may be fast, but I can't be *Agent86 fast* all the time.

Comment: These two guys with diamonds are correct.  Just because it's answerable doesn't mean it's a question category we should encourage.  We discussed it on chat as the situation was developing, and I answered it at the time and shortly thereafter we decided it would be better as a comment.  Sorry for any confusion!

Answer (score 7):

This has been debated in Meta pretty thoroughly previously.

See [this question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/why-did-they-design-it-that-way-anyway-and-why-do-we-allow-or-disallow-thes):

Quoth Matthew Read:

> They should be disallowed.
>
> The [...] problem I see: They're not real questions. Beyond the facet
>   that many aren't answerable, they contradict this guideline from the
>   FAQ:
>
> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual
>   problems that you face.
>
> "I'm wondering why they did this" is not a real problem needing a
>   solution from the perspective of a gamer. How to deal with or alter
>   the game mechanics may be a problem, but the "why" of it is not. Game
>   devs might legitimately wonder about this as they design and market
>   their games, so again they might be better on Game Dev; but they are
>   not useful here.

[This question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2291/game-canon-questions-which-extend-beyond-the-context-of-the-story-and-its-materi) doesn't apply in this case, but it's answer is also relevant.

Quoth Grace Note:

> I was once discussing with another moderator of another site about a
>   theoretical "No one cares" close reason. I didn't really support it,
>   on the bounds that Not A Real Question generally covers it, as does
>   the new and improved Too Localized:
>
> This question is unlikely to ever help any future visitors; it is only
>   relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an
>   extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to
>   the worldwide audience of the internet.
>
> As such, I feel that the ties to the context of the story or game
>   figure heavily into the scope of who actually is interested in such
>   plot questions. I am willing to be corrected about the ties of this
>   particular question to the context of Portal, and will support its
>   reopening in that scenario. But I feel that more importantly, we
>   shouldn't simply allow a question and disregard the context just
>   because we can answer it.