# Would you like to offload your 'lore Q' to Sci-fi&Fantasy SE via community ads?

Tags: discussion, advertisements

> There are many of us on Arqade who would [very much like to offload some of the "lore" questions](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5325/why-did-people-vote-to-close-this-question-about-harbinger-in-me3) [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2258/what-is-the-point-in-the-community-promotion-ads-that-go-to-this-site#comment5515_2259), so advertising [there](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3352/community-promotion-ads-2012) would definitely be good. – [Mark Trapp](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/366/mark-trapp)

Is this true? I know that the two communities are quite different, and there may be a bit of ill will about some of our...[less good questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6038/what-are-the-special-abilities-of-wesley-crusher/17511#17511).

But we can, and do answer video-game [questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-games).

Rather than making up some ad from our site that might not fit in here with your ads, would you like to design something that would (hopefully) draw the bad questions out?

I've posted in the [sci-fi meta too](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2261/a-call-to-arms-i-mean-ads-for-gaming-stackexchange), in case you like what you see.

Comment: A useful moment to remind us of our current lore policy, afaik: videogame lore questions are _acceptable_ so long as it is covered by the videogame's canon (including auxiliary books and the such). For example "Why doesn't Aperture Science use portals to create infinite energy?" is out (or answerable only with "the canon doesn't say").

Answer (score 7):

Yikes: had I known my comment would be used as a "call to arms", I would've chosen my words more carefully. To expand:

1. Lore is technically not off-topic here.
2. There are some "bad"<sup>1</sup> lore questions that get asked here that many of us don't like and wish were asked somewhere else.
3. I *personally* think SciFi.SE is a good place for that.

I don't think Arqade should be the ones to funnel lore questions we don't like to SciFi, either through some sort of policy<sup>2</sup> and/or through an Arqade-originated advertising campaign: besides the fact that [it's discouraged to pass the buck like that](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/), there are many here who don't think all that highly of SciFi.SE and probably wouldn't want to see us do any sort of heavy promotion for it or make it a rule to funnel people to it.

Rather, the intent behind my comment was to get one or two of [the "SciFi ad on SciFi" submissions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2258/what-is-the-point-in-the-community-promotion-ads-that-go-to-this-site) posted in our [Community Promotion Ads thread](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3352/community-promotion-ads-2012), much like [Chess.SE has done](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5001/3389), to get the word out that Arqade doesn't have to be the only place you think of [when you want to ask why something only has four claws](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5325/why-did-people-vote-to-close-this-question-about-harbinger-in-me3).

<sup>Note 1: "bad" in the sense that they don't really help you do better in a game except in the abstract sense</sup>
<sup>Note 2: *unless* the Arqade community decides that all lore is off-topic, which doesn't seem to be likely any time in the near future</sup>

Comment: Last paragraph was what I was after really! That's what I'd like to see.

Comment: Why do people not think highly of SciFi.SE?

Comment: @OghmaOsiris I assume they're just jealous of our spaceships and dragons.

Comment: @Keen And the [Ashley-Judd](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1022), [is-MLP-Canon-with-Star-Trek](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6650/is-my-little-pony-friendship-is-magic-canon-with-star-trek), [Star-Trek-couch](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1367/what-is-a-star-trek-couch), [Santa-Claus-Timelord](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7837/is-santa-claus-a-time-lord), and [what-happens-when-a-zombie,-vampire,-and-werewolf-mix](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3654/bitten-by-a-vampire-werewolf-and-zombie-what-happens-to-him) questions.