# Why was this question mod opened?

Tags: discussion, reopen

I noticed a question was mod reopened. Specifically, [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/148029/what-are-the-minecraft-easter-eggs). Normally, I wouldn't even care, as questions being reopened are a cause for celebration, as it means they've been fixed to be acceptable.

The problem is...this question hasn't been changed at all. There was a [meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8133/what-defines-a-question-as-being-too-broad-when-asking-about-easter-eggs) about it, where as near as I can tell, the most up voted answers are, "vote your opinion". There's nothing in it that's heavily upvoted, either way, so I'm wondering why a mod decided to unilaterally counter my and four others' close votes.

Since there is no majority consensus on the meta, I would either prefer some feedback from the mod in question, or a mod re-close. Or both. My attempt to engage said mod in chat about it was ignored, so I have no other option but to take it to the community.

Comment: Now that it has been community opened, I have no issue with it.  My entire issue was with it being reopened by moderator fiat.

Answer (score 11):

The question got flagged with that meta as being evidence that it should be reopened.  I read over the answers to that meta and it seemed like the consensus was that "if the size of the answer is not too broad, easter egg questions are okay."

The scope of the answer seems defined by the accepted answer on the question.  I looked at that answer, and it did not seem overlong for the SE format.  There were lesser answers that seemed to repeat bits of the accepted answer, which seemed irrelevant to the decision at hand.  I was inclined to agree with the flagger that it belonged open.  I opened it.

I did not consider a flagged question re-open to be by moderator fiat, but another moderator disagreed and re-closed the question.  I have no plans to contest this decision on his part and will accept any decision by the community that my actions were incorrect.

Comment: I don't see why this is too broad. We have loads of questions like 'what are all the x in y' (http://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=what+are+all+the) and I don't see what the difference of this one is.

Comment: @Shanodin Too broad isn't something we have a hard and fast ruleset for. Its up to personal opinion. Which, for this question, was deemed too broad.

Comment: @shanodin the difference, and the source of the judgment call referred to in the prior meta question, is the quantity of the x in y. I'm not going to pretend to know that number in that instance, but if you think it doesn't matter, you're completely missing the point.

Comment: @Frank/Less - We don't have to be the compendium of the whole list. Put the major/interesting ones in an answer, link to the [Minecraft Wikia Easter Eggs](http://minecraft.wikia.com/wiki/Easter_Eggs) page for more reference/further reading, protect the question to stop new user spam and call it a day.

Comment: @Robotnik But then we would do the same for everything else too: "First you do this and then this and that, but since the question is too broad, I'll just leave a link to the rest of the content". I don't think it's useful to give half-answers purely because the question is too broad.